# .Net MAUI startup crash System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: ios, xamarin, migration, cross-platform, maui

(Edit: initially I was getting an null exception, this moved to the TagetInvocation after removing the appcenter Nugets, and finally now getting this exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException)

I am trying to migrate a Xamarin Forms app to MAUI.
and I tried a few ways to do this from various source including MS.
In the end I just created a new App and moved my files to the new project, and updated what needed to be in the .cs and in the .xaml files. removed the Nugets that where not compatible and the code that was associated with them.

the remaining Nugets are:

- Plugin.BLE
- sqlite-net-pcl
- CommunityToolKit.Maui

So I am where the app can compile. but when I launch it is will crash with exception 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'.
which is thrown at the line for `InitializeComponent();` in the App class constructor.

the App class and xaml files are the same as when the project was created.

```xml
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
<Application
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EGrid18"
                 x:Class="EGrid18.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

```cs
namespace EGrid18;

public partial class App: Application {

  public App() {
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new AppShell();
  }
}
```

this is the stack trace (edited).

```
at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext)
       
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalGetSatelliteAssembly(Assembly assembly, CultureInfo culture, Version version, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound)
```

EGrid18.App.InitializeComponent() in /Users/.../Microsoft.Maui.Controls.SourceGen/Microsoft.Maui.Controls.SourceGen.CodeBehindGenerator/App.xaml.sg.cs:22
EGrid18.App..ctor() in /Users/.../EGrid18/App.xaml.cs:12
EGrid18.Program.Main(string[] args) in /Users/.../EGrid18/Platforms/MacCatalyst/Program.cs:13

And I am utterly clueless why it's crashing as far as I know all the code should be ok.
If any one as any clue or ideal to what I should look at I will be very happy to get some help here.

EDIT: This was a problem from the VS mac it self, as the MS team waited till the official launch of Xcode 14 to test compatibility and fix problems. The new update from VS fixed the problem.

Comment: This problem was caused by losing the dll file or can not find the file.

Comment: What dll file? Please elaborate. Is there a solution for this problem?